# Removing an specific item from an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wc2ons?file=src%2FSection.js

I have sections, and i can add items to those sections. How can i delete some item? I tried

```
const removeItem = (i) => {
    setSections((section) => {
      const itemTarget = section.items[i];
      const filtered = section.items.filter((item) => item !== itemTarget);
      return {
        ...section,
        items: filtered,
      };
    });
  };
```

But for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: Just so you know, `removeItem` is returning `undefined`.  And the return value from `setSections` is not used anywhere.. Without any error logs or other details, I think you should look at these two aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `setSections`, but you return a single section instead of an array of sections. You probably need something like this:

```js
// using the `section` variable from the upper scope
const removeItem = (i) => {
    setSections((sections) => {
      const itemTarget = section.items[i];
      const filtered = section.items.filter((item) => item !== itemTarget);
      const newSections = [...sections];
      newSections[section.id] = {
        ...section,
        items: filtered,
      };
      return newSections;
    });
  };
```

A few tips (you don't have to follow them): TypeScript can prevent such mistakes and give useful error messages. Immer.js can make writing such code simpler.

Comment: It's working! So the newSections is just a copy of the array sections defined on the parent component right? And the newSections[section.id], i changed it to `newSections[index]`, where index is the index of the map of the parent component. So `{...section, items:filtered}`, you are just changing the items property right?

Comment: Yes, `[...sections]` is creating a copy of the sections array. `{...section, items: filtered}` is creating a new object with the `items` property overridden.

Answer (score 1):

The `removeItem` callback prop you pass into the `Section` component is the way to go and you should get rid of passing `setSections` down to it as well.

```
removeItem={(i) => removeItem(index, i)}
```

Child components shouldn't do parent's work so you had it right at first, I'm going to help you implement that since I can already see the `removeItem` handler being there in the `App` component.

`removeItem` has already all the info you need, I'm going to rename the arguments so it's more clear.

```js
const removeItem = (sectionIndex, index) => {
  const newSections = sections.slice();
  const newItems = newSections[sectionIndex].items.slice();
  
  newItems.splice(index, 1);
  newSections[sectionIndex].items = newItems;
  
  setSections(newSections);
};
```

Then get rid of `removeItem` implementation in the `Section` component and destructure it from the props.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `section` is an *array*. So you are currently accessing the undefined property `items` on it. You would have to change your *function* to something like this

```
  const removeItem = (i) => {
    setSections((section) /* aqui vc tinha chamado de prev*/ => {
      const itemTarget = section[i].items[j];
      const filtered = section[i].items.filter((item) => item !== itemTarget);
      return [...section, {
        ...section[i],
        items: filtered,
      }]
    });
  };
```

where `i` is the section in question and `j` is the item you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

here is a crude solution to your problem (i noticed other bugs in the code but this solves your issue with removing items at least), but i would separate the sections and items into separate components that in turn has its own states.
There you can add/remove items withing its parent section much more easily.

Now we have to work around this by looking for which section the code wants to remove the current item in.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xxbvp1?file=src%2FSection.js